# Are there benefits in having manager in your title in software industry?

Tags: software-industry

I'm a senior software engineer who started managing people (other devs). The company won't change my title to software engineering manager now (don't know in the future).

My question is if it is important to have manager in your title for future job interviews. Will they be more incline to ignore my application to an engineering manager role because of that? Even if I have the same responsibilities?

I'm asking this because I'm not sure how hard and often should I push for the title change.

Comment: The answer would vary depending upon your location.  In the west, probably no importance.  In many Eastern cultures, a significant importance.

Comment: I once worked for a company that called all software developers "managers". That helped when I needed to stop services for an apartment they rented. The phone company asked for my title and accepted the stop order because I was a "manager".

Comment: In the US, many banks give the title "Vice President" to senior software engineers, team lead software engineers, or software managers.  That may be very surprising for many people who have not worked as software engineers in big banks in the US. BTW, the head of a local office in a US bank also has the title "Vice President".

Comment: @Jake, One possible reason that your company has not given the title "Manager" to you is that they will have to give you a large one-time salary increase when they officially promote you to the "Manager" position, and maybe they will have to pay a manager a larger annual raise compared to other normal team leads.

Comment: If you intend to continue on a leadership path, then yes, it's very important. If you don't care about these responsibilities and intend to just continue being an engineer, then no, it's not even a little important.

Comment: Note that there are a lot of positions, such as Release Manager, which use that word without necessarily implying any leadership role, and others such as Team Lead which reverse that. Which illustrates why the focus is on the description rather than the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is if it is important to have manager in your title for
> future job interviews. Will they be more incline to ignore my
> application to an engineering manager role because of that? Even if I
> have the same responsibilities?

Certainly you would have an easier path to an interview for an experienced manager role, if you already have "Manager" in your title.

It might not make a huge difference, but it will certainly be an advantage.

> I'm asking this because I'm not sure how hard and often should I push
> for the title change.

If you see yourself on the management path going forward, you might want to push for the title. Ask what you have to do to earn the title.

Answer (score 4):

Job titles are very inconsistent between companies and industries and hiring managers know this.  What's important is your level of responsibility and your results.

So if you write (assuming it's true) something like the following on your resume/CV, then readers will understand:

*"I managed a team of N software developers who delivered a USDxxx project under budget and on schedule."*

Obviously there is more to it than just this.  If you're interviewing for a management job they will want to know HOW you did this but that's something you can prepare to discuss prior to your interview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's important - but elsewhere.

Manger does entirely different job than engineer. It's a completely different skill set. If possible, nobody hires engineers for managing nor managers for engineering.

However, the title at your current company means very little (at least in the Western culture). The only place where it matters is your resume / LinkedIn profile / etc, because that's where potential future employers can see it. Your company is possibly reluctant to change it internally because they have different pay grades so change of title would force a pay rise. It's widely understood so "I moved to management while my title did not" won't sound suspicious. They'll be hiring you for your skill, not for past title (at least those worth working for).

From my experience, most companies I worked for had absolutely no guidelines about what employees should put in their LinkedIn, so I could put anything there. You should check how this would be viewed at your company. Even if they oppose, you can use it as a leverage to change your title officially - as long as your description is more accurate than theirs.

I don't want to second guess your judgement, but for most people you're X when more than 50% of your time is spent doing X. This can also be a source of disagreement, if your transition is gradual and your managing duties are mixed with engineering duties. Even if - in your opinion - you devote most of your time to managing, the higher-ups might still have most of your time billed under "engineering".

Comment: *"Manger does entirely different job than engineer. It's a completely different skill set."* - I think that is overstating the case. Orchestrating the work of machinery involves many of the same skills as orchestrating the work of people.

Comment: @Steve I work in IT as a programmer. I never had a manager that knew programming, simply because programmers cost more than low-level managers. So I was managed by people who had absolutely no skills in the field they were managing. That didn't hindered them in doing great job. Also, I tried managing once and was quite bad at it. That brings me to a conclusion that those skill sets do not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a senior software engineer who started managing people (other
> devs).

Yes, it is important, and since the truth is that you've filled a management role at your current position, you can safely bill yourself as ***manager***, regardless of the title which your current firm gives you, which is rather irrelevant.

In the specifics of your experience, detail your management experience, as @jwh20 has explained:

> *I managed a team of N software developers who delivered a USDxx*x
> *project under budget and on schedule.*

etc.

You will be entirely honest and above-board in doing so.

IMO, if you run across someone who finds it disturbing that the title on your resume doesn't match your title at your current job, although your experience reflects the truth of your resume lead, that's not someone you'd want to work for.